# Does OracleDataSource Connection pool keeps the connections open after the process is completed?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, database-connection, connection-pooling

Hi I have been working with the oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource. I have given min connections as 3 and max connections as 10. This is my connection pool configuration.

```
<bean id="datasources" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
<property name="URL" value="****" />
<property name="user" value="****" />
<property name="password" value="****" />
<property name="connectionCacheProperties">
<props merge="default">
<prop key="MinLimit">3</prop>
<prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

This is in a context file say datasource.xml. This context is loaded in a method called run(). This run() method is called every minute through SpringScheduler.

I have got complaint from DBA that more than 600 connections are open and remains unused. I am closing the connections in my code everywhere after use. So my question is about the min no of connections I have given in datasource.xml file. Will it still be open after the process is completed during a scheduler interval? I mean everytime my scheduler loads this config, what happens to the connections that were opened last time?

EDIT 1: I have even changed the MinLimit and MaxLimit to 0 and 3 respectively. Still the same issue.

Can I load the DB context from the scheduler context xml?

EDIT 2: I have redesigned my SB structure based on the suggestions. I have avoided loading the DB configurations every time. Instead I loaded the DB configuration along with Scheduler configuration. Now the issue is solved. But still I would like to know if there is any option in OracleDataSource to delete the created connections after the a particular idle time?

Comment: Never load a context because you have to. Use dependency injection for that. What you are doing is creating a new datasource each time you need a connection, opening 3 connections, so after a certain amount of time you will have a lot of open connections. So as stated, don't load it, use dependency injection. Basically your approach is flawed.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not clear about what you are suggesting. I need a particular instance to run every minute. So I have used a Scheduler context for that. This scheduler will trigger a run() method. In this run() method, I am loading the context for datasources and other beans because I require the datasource for DB operations. So If I need to inject a bean, that should be loaded from the context file I am loading. Or are you suggesting to give the datasource and beans from the scheduler context?

Comment: Never load the context, each time it runs you are creating a datasource. SO never load it. All of your configuration should be loaded outside of that bean and injected into it. Then in your run method use the beans don't load them.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand your suggestion. I have redesigned my SB instance. The issue is resolved now.